# How to fix list items inside drawer in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, listitem, drawer

A few days ago I posted a question here:

[How to expand more/less only one ListItem using single method in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029067/how-to-expand-more-less-only-one-listitem-using-single-method-in-react)

I have got an incomplete answer here, and I accept it (don't know why I did this, it looks like it was working at the first place). I have to admit that my question here was maybe a little unclear.

So, long story short, I want to fix my list items inside drawer to work properly. By properly I mean this:

- When I click on expandable item it should expand only that (clicked) item. (this is working)
- When I click on another expandable item, it should expand that item, but close previously opened. (not working)
- When I click on item inside expandable item (in all cases it is view or add) it should NOT close that expandable item. (not working, now is closing all items)

Here is my improved code in this sidebar component:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import ExpandLess from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ExpandableItem from "./expendable-item";

import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import SupervisorAccountIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SupervisorAccount";
import AccessibilityNewIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccessibilityNew";
import FaceIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Face';
import FitnessCenterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FitnessCenter';
import EventIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Event';
import PanoramaWideAngleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PanoramaWideAngle';
import ReceiptIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Receipt';
import PhoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Phone';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import VisibilityIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

const drawerWidth = 280;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerContainer: {
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function SideBar({ gymId }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const NonExpandableItemContainer = ({ 
    icon, 
    menuItemName, 
    menuItemLink 
  }) => (
    <ListItem 
      button 
      component={Link} 
      to={menuItemLink}
    >
      <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={menuItemName} />
    </ListItem>
  );

  const ExpandableItemContainer = ({
    icon,
    menuItemName,
    firstItemName,
    firstItemLink,
    secondItemName,
    secondItemLink,
  }) => (
    <ExpandableItem
      render={(xprops) => (
        <>
          <ListItem button 
            onClick={
              (menuItemName) => xprops.setOpen(!xprops.open, menuItemName)
            }
          >
            <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={menuItemName} />
            {xprops.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={xprops.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={firstItemLink}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <VisibilityIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={firstItemName} />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={secondItemLink}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <AddIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={secondItemName} />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );

  return (
    <Drawer
      className={classes.drawer}
      variant="permanent"
      classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper,
      }}
    >
      <Toolbar />
      <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
        <List
          component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          className={classes.root}
        >
          <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<HomeIcon />}
            menuItemName="Home"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/home"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<SupervisorAccountIcon />}
            menuItemName="Administrators"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<AccessibilityNewIcon />}
            menuItemName="Trainers"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<FaceIcon />}
            menuItemName="Users"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<FitnessCenterIcon />}
            menuItemName="Trainings"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewTrainings"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addTraining"}
          />
          <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<EventIcon />}
            menuItemName="Schedules"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewTrainingSchedules"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<PanoramaWideAngleIcon />}
            menuItemName="Halls"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewHalls"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addHall"}
          />
          <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<ReceiptIcon />}
            menuItemName="Pricelist"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewPricelist"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addPricelistItem"}
          />
          <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<PhoneIcon />}
            menuItemName="Contact"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/contact"}
          />
          <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<SettingsIcon />}
            menuItemName="Settings"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/settings"}
          />
        </List>
      </div>
    </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Here is code of my helper expandable-item component here:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ExpandableItem = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  console.log(props.menuItemName);
  return props.render({ open, setOpen });
};

export default ExpandableItem;
```

I was searching on material-ui and found something similar, but I couldn't manage to merge this. Here is the link of material-ui accordions:

https://material-ui.com/components/accordion/

As you can see, the functionality of Customized accordions is very similar to that what I need. If you expand one collapsible group it shows the content. If you after that choose the other one it expends and shows the content, and close the previous one.

What is the best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing the current expanded panel name (or id)

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ExpandableItem = props => {
    const [itemState, setItemState] = useState({open: false, menuItemName: ""});

    console.log(props.menuItemName);
    return props.render({ itemState, setItemState });
};

export default ExpandableItem;
```

i've renamed the variables [open, setOpen] to [itemState, setItemState], so need to change wherever its used, (alternatively you can add separate variable
for setting the currently selected menuName)

and in your ExpandableItemContainer, in the onClick handler pass the appropriate values
xprops.setItemState({open:!xprops.itemState.open, menuItemName}})

also in the Collapse component for the in Prop change as

in={xprops.itemState.open && menuItemName === xprops.itemState.menuItemName}

```
  const ExpandableItemContainer = ({
    icon,
    menuItemName,
    firstItemName,
    firstItemLink,
    secondItemName,
    secondItemLink,
  }) => (
    <ExpandableItem
      render={(xprops) => (
        <>
          <ListItem button 
            onClick={
              (menuItemName) => xprops.setItemState({open:!xprops.itemState.open, menuItemName}})
            }
          >
            <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={menuItemName} />
            {xprops.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={xprops.itemState.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={firstItemLink}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <VisibilityIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={firstItemName} />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={secondItemLink}
              >
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <AddIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={secondItemName} />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
```

if you want to toggle the selection you'd need to maintain the state at the top level(list  instead of the listItem level
Like below

```
export default function SideBar() {
const classes = useStyles();
const gymId = 1;
const [itemState, setItemState] = React.useState({
    open: false,
    menuItemName: ""
});

const NonExpandableItemContainer = ({ icon, menuItemName, menuItemLink }) => (
    <ListItem button component={Link} to={menuItemLink}>
    <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary={menuItemName} />
    </ListItem>
);

const ExpandableItemContainer = ({
    icon,
    menuItemName,
    firstItemName,
    firstItemLink,
    secondItemName,
    secondItemLink
}) => (
    <ExpandableItem
    render={xprops => (
        <>
        <ListItem
            button
            onClick={() =>
            setItemState({
                open:
                menuItemName === itemState.menuItemName
                    ? !itemState.open
                    : true,
                menuItemName
            })
            }
        >
            <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={menuItemName} />
            {itemState.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse
            in={itemState.open && menuItemName === itemState.menuItemName}
            timeout="auto"
            unmountOnExit
        >
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={firstItemLink}
            >
                <ListItemIcon>
                <VisibilityIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={firstItemName} />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem
                button
                className={classes.nested}
                component={Link}
                to={secondItemLink}
            >
                <ListItemIcon>
                <AddIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={secondItemName} />
            </ListItem>
            </List>
        </Collapse>
        </>
    )}
    />
);

return (
    <Drawer
    className={classes.drawer}
    variant="permanent"
    classes={{
        paper: classes.drawerPaper
    }}
    >
    <Toolbar />
    <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
        <List
        component="nav"
        aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
        className={classes.root}
        >
        <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<HomeIcon />}
            menuItemName="Home"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/home"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<SupervisorAccountIcon />}
            menuItemName="Administrators"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<AccessibilityNewIcon />}
            menuItemName="Trainers"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<FaceIcon />}
            menuItemName="Members"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewAccount"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addAccount"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<FitnessCenterIcon />}
            menuItemName="Trainings"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewTrainings"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addTraining"}
        />
        <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<EventIcon />}
            menuItemName="Training schedules"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewTrainingSchedules"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<PanoramaWideAngleIcon />}
            menuItemName="Halls"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewHalls"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addHall"}
        />
        <ExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<ReceiptIcon />}
            menuItemName="Pricelist"
            firstItemName="View"
            firstItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/viewPricelist"}
            secondItemName="Add"
            secondItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/addPricelistItem"}
        />
        <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<PhoneIcon />}
            menuItemName="Contact"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/contact"}
        />
        <NonExpandableItemContainer
            icon={<SettingsIcon />}
            menuItemName="Settings"
            menuItemLink={"/gym/" + gymId + "/settings"}
        />
        </List>
    </div>
    </Drawer>
);
}
```

codesandbox link: https://otzsl.csb.app/

Comment: This is one step closer to the solution, but still not there... I have added this  console.log(itemState); to my expandable-item.js, and now it shows on every click boolean open and string menuItemMenu which is good. When I click on Administrators, it shows {open: true, menuItemName: "Administrators"}, and when I click on Trainers it shows {open: true, menuItemName: "Trainers"}... but, why is my menu item administrators still true? It should become false, it should close it. I think that this expandable-item.js should expande with code to change previous itemState open to false...

Comment: can you change Collapse in flag to  xprops.itemState.open like
 <Collapse in={xprops.itemState.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>

Comment: Still nothing... Try yourself on this link: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-leavitt-3cmyb?file=/src/expandableItem.js

Comment: @Nemanja updated answer, here's the link https://otzsl.csb.app/

Comment: That's it! Thank you!